# Installing Ubuntu from windows

Tags: 12.10, wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu with the windows installer but I want to make the partition larger than 30 GB. How do i do this?

Comment: *I am trying to install Ubuntu with the windows installer but I want to make the partition larger than 30 gb. How do i do this?* - You **can't** that's how Wubi is set. Wubi is not intended to be used full-on time, it's for you to try Ubuntu and then properly install the OS on a partition(s).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to but in Wubi disk/dvd and with Gparted create an extended partition. Attention! You could lose data!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest u use VmWare Workstation. It'll install ubuntu in a Virtual Machine and you can switch from Ubuntu to windows or vice versa without booting the system.